# Creating table using select statement from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, select, create-table

I have this university task to create table using SELECT statement from multiple tables, but it's not as simple... here's basic info:

I'm using 2 tables -

```
CITY(city_ID, name);
PERSON(person_ID, name, surname, city_ID); 
--city_ID is FK indicating in which city person was born.
```

Now my task is to create new table

```
STATISTICS(city_ID, city_name, number_of_births);
--number_of_births is basically a count of people born in each city
```

Problem is that I have to use only SELECT statement to do so.

I've tried something like this: (I'm well aware that this cannot possibly work but as to give you a better idea where I'm stuck)

```
CREATE TABLE Statistics AS 
(SELECT city.city_ID, city.name as "city_name", number_of_births AS 
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM person WHERE person.city_id = city.city_id)
 FROM city, person);
```

Comment: What DBMS? Sql Server? MySql? Oracle?

Comment: Damn! forgot to add tag, it's ORACLE @DaveZych

Comment: Ha! You can try my answer, but I don't think that's the correct syntax for Oracle. If not let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: I've rewriten it to match oracle dialect and everything seems to work just fine! Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because it's not valid for Oracle. Add an answer with what you did and accept yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server you can do `SELECT * INTO`. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
INTO Statistics
FROM (
    SELECT 
        city.city_ID, 
        city.name as "city_name", 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM person WHERE person.city_id = city.city_id) as 'number_of_births'
    FROM city
        inner join person on city.city_id = person.city_id
) t1
```

Comment: `SELECT INTO` is sql server syntax.. just create table as will do, you got it!

Comment: That is invalid for Oracle. I can't understand how that got accepted.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added this answer prior to him adding the Oracle tag. Then he accepted it. I honestly don't know either.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

Ok, this got really messy. Dave Zych's answer was correct when rewritten in Oracle dialect.

```
CREATE TABLE Statistics AS SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        city.city_ID, 
        city.name AS "City_name",
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM person WHERE person.city_ID = city.city_ID) AS "number_of_births"
         FROM city  INNER JOIN person ON city.city_ID = person.city_ID);
```